# How do I seperate AdView and NestedScrollView from each other and stop them from overlaping in android studio?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I am trying to create a space for my adView banner ad in android studio but the adView is overlapping my widget NestedScrollView, and is covering the words at the bottom which are in the NestedScrollView. All of my xml code is encased in a widget ConstraintLayout. How do I seperate the adView and NestedScrollView widget from overlapping one another? This is the current format of my android studio activity_main.xml page

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/grey"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/ScrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your NestedScrollView's height is set to match_parent this makes it the size of the ConstraintSet.
If you set it to 0dp and constrain top to top of the parent and bottom to top of the
adView it would layout with the two separated.

```xml
    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/ScrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"  
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/adView"  >
```